# Java - count and rename filenames

Tags: java

I have to read through files in a folder and rename them.  In this case, there are 3 files with parrot in the name, 4 with joker and 4 with buzz.

I can get the words buzz, parrot and buzz using substring.  But i have to go through them and count how many times each occurs and then name them as 01,02,03,... once it is grouped.  I'm having hard time with it.  Any suggestions is helpful.

Original Filename

apple_orange_buzz_banana01.txt
apple_orange_buzz_banana02.txt
apple_orange_buzz_banana05.txt
apple_orange_buzz_banana06.txt
apple_orange_joker_banana03.txt
apple_orange_joker_banana04.txt
apple_orange_joker_banana07.txt
apple_orange_joker_banana10.txt
apple_orange_parrot_banana08.txt
apple_orange_parrot_banana09.txt
apple_orange_parrot_banana11.txt

Rename Filename

buzz01.txt
buzz02.txt
buzz03.txt
buzz04.txt

joker01.txt
joker02.txt
joker03.txt
joker04.txt

parrot01.txt
parrot02.txt
parrot03.txt

Thank you

Comment: Are `buzz`es, `joker`s and `parrot`s consecutive? Can you have buzz, joker, buzz, parrot, etc. as input ?

Comment: They are not consecutive.  I just ordered it that way to make it clear to read.  There are about 50-80 files in that folder.

Comment: Use regular expression

Comment: Use File.listFiles(FilenameFilter filter) for ervery group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Map to store counter for each kind of file (buzz, joker, ...) and regex to find part of name you are interested in.

So your code can look like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("apple_orange_(\\w+)_banana\\d+[.]txt");
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

File dir = new File("d:/zzz");//path to directory containing your files
File[] files = dir.listFiles();//you can provide file filter here
Arrays.sort(files);//lets make sure that files are sort alphabetically

for (File f : files) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(f.getName());
    if (m.find()) {
        String name = m.group(1);
        int counter = map.getOrDefault(name, 0) + 1;
        map.put(name, counter);
        f.renameTo(new File(dir, String.format("%s%02d.txt", name, counter)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the files alphabetically, then split the file name into an array and rename:

```
//get list of files
String path = "C:/Users/your/folder/";
File folder = new File(path);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

//this will sort alphabetically
java.util.Collections.sort(listOfFiles);

String mainPart = "";
int counter = 1;

for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        //get parts
        String[] parts = file.getName()).split("_");

        //note: make sure file name has consistent formatting
        if(!mainPart.equals(parts[2])){
            mainPart = parts[2];
            counter = 1;
        }

        //keep track if the number needs a leading zero.
        String zero = ""
        if(counter < 10)
            zero = "0";

        //note: check to see if renameTo was successful
        file.renameTo(new File(path + mainPart + zero + counter + ".txt"));
        counter++;      
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code out, so there may be minor syntax errors. But you get the idea.

Comment: Just going off my eyes here, but would the file be renamed to `01` or `02`? I think you need a `DecimalFormat` object for the counter.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Updated to add 0 for digits 1-9.

Comment: You guys are all awesome.  So many different ideas.  I'll try working on it and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this my creating a `Map` with the new file prefix as the key and the list of files to be renamed as the values. Then loop over them a rename them.

Not sure from where the list of files come but you can get the gist from this:

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

files.add(new File("apple_orange_buzz_banana01.txt"));
files.add(new File("apple_orange_buzz_banana02.txt"));
files.add(new File("apple_orange_buzz_banana05.txt"));
files.add(new File("apple_orange_buzz_banana06.txt"));


files.add(new File("apple_orange_joker_banana03.txt"));
files.add(new File("apple_orange_joker_banana04.txt"));
files.add(new File("apple_orange_joker_banana07.txt"));
files.add(new File("apple_orange_joker_banana10.txt"));

files.add(new File("apple_orange_parrot_banana08.txt"));
files.add(new File("apple_orange_parrot_banana09.txt"));
files.add(new File("apple_orange_parrot_banana11.txt"));


Map<String,List<File>> prefixMap = new HashMap<String,List<File>>();

for (File f : files) {
    String[] splits = f.getName().split("_");

    if (splits.length == 4) {
        String prefix = splits[2];
        if (!prefixMap.containsKey(prefix)) {
            prefixMap.put(prefix, new ArrayList<File>());
        }
        prefixMap.get(prefix).add(f);
    }
}

// Now rename them
for (String p : prefixMap.keySet()) {
    int counter = 1;

    for (File f : prefixMap.get(p)) {
        f.renameTo(new File(p+String.format("%02d", counter)+".txt"));
        counter++;
    }
}
```